# ffmpeg stereo3d filter not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I followed [the FFmpeg wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Stereoscopic) for trying to convert my side-by-side video to above/below format.

I typed this line:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf stereo3d=sbs1:ab1 output.mp4
```

and the system replied:

```
Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'sbs1'
Unable to parse option value 'sbs1"
Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'ab1'
Unable to parse option value 'ab1"
Error setting option in to value sbs1.
Error applying options to the filter.
Error initializing filter 'stereo3d' with args 'sbs1:ab1'
Error opening filters!
```

I re-installed a fresh copy of ffmpeg but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `ab1` but `abl` — with a lowercase L, not a 1.